# Why does Perl not warn if using an undeclared variable in another namespace - and how can I be warned about this?

Tags: perl, variables, warnings

I am using `strict` and `warning` in my Perl scripts to be notified if I am using undeclared variables. Thus, the interpreter will warn that `$foo` is undeclared in the following scriptlet:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$foo = 'bar';
print ($foo);
```

However, if I use an undeclared variable in another namespace, I am not warned. The following scriptlet runs without warning whatsoever.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$BAR::foo = 'bar';
print ($BAR::foo);
```

Why is this difference?

Since I have lost quite some time figuring out exactly this problem, albeit in a much larger context, I am wondering if it is possible to make Perl me warn about using undeclared variables in other namespaces, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you fully specify the namespace in which a variable belongs, `perl` assumes you know what you are doing. See [`perldoc strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html):

> #### `strict vars`
>
> This generates a compile-time error if you access a variable that was neither explicitly declared (using any of `my`, `our`, `state`, or `use vars`) nor fully qualified.

I don't think there is a way to detect that you have specified a non-existent variable `$BAR::foo`. However, if the `BAR` package is under your control, you can avoid using package variables in the first place by mediating access to the state of `foo` using accessors, and hiding the variable from other modules.

The answer to problems created by using global variables is not to use global variables.

Comment: Re "*I don't think there is a way to detect that you have specified a non-existent variable `$BAR::foo`*", No, that's not it. If Perl can tell that the variable wasn't used, it can do so whether no matter how it's named in the code.

Answer (score 4):

> #### `strict vars`
>
> This generates a compile-time error if you access a variable that was neither explicitly declared (using any of `my`, `our`, `state`, or `use vars`) nor fully qualified.

Perl "trusts" users when they use fully-qualified var names. I suspect it's to allow users to sets config variables in modules that don't use `use strict;`.

For example, let's look at the following snippet using Data::Dumper:

```
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper($s));
```

Even long after `use strict;` was introduced, Data::Dumper didn't declare `$Useqq`. There wouldn't even have been a mechanism to do so before `use strict;`! So the above snippet would be using an undeclared variable. That means strict code would not have been able to use Data::Dumper in the above fashion if `strict vars` was enforced covered fully-qualified names.

It doesn't make sense to prevent strict code from using modules that aren't strict-safe, so `strict vars` doesn't cover fully-qualified names. These are rare enough and easily-identifiable enough to simply have programmers take more care when using them.

---

> *I am wondering if it is possible to make Perl me warn about using undeclared variables in other namespaces, too.*

I don't know of existing solutions. It might be possible to hook into Perl to do that, but it would be very hard.

Keep in mind that Perl already warns you if you only use a package variable once, so this should help you catch typos.